# Integer literal error while putting binary value to integer variable

Tags: java

Java version: 1.8.0
Code:

```
int x= 0B1010;
System.out.println("x = " + x);
```

Error:

```
';' expected
int x= 0B1010;
1 error
```

Please clear this doubt
Thanks...!

Comment: Version 7+ is needed for binary literal support, use decimal/hex notation.

Comment: @AlexK. Or, `int x = Integer.parseInt("1010", 2);`

Comment: I would prefer `int x = 10; // b1010`

Comment: thanks...!  alex K